# "AlternateVersions" alternative in Amazon PA-API 5.0

Tags: amazon-product-api

According to the [official documentation](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/migration-guide/pa-api-40-to-50-mapping.html) the "[AlternateVersions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_AlternateVersions.html)" parameter is deprecated in Amazon's Product Advertising API 5.0. I can't seem to figure out the alternative way to find related product versions. Can anyone help? Thank you!